# Calling `getBudgetId` in the Google Adwords API from Scala

Tags: scala, google-ads-api

In Google Adwords API, this is the Java code to get the budget id:

```
Long budgetId = budgetService.mutate(new BudgetOperation[] {budgetOperation}).getValue(0).getBudgetId();
```

I need to convert this to Scala code as I am working with Google AdWords API in Scala.

Comment: Why don't you spend some time on Scala tutorials?  Then you will be able to convert code like this yourself fairly easily, and you will understand why you are writing the Scala code instead of mimicking a transformation that someone else gave to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation to Scala is pretty straightforward: immutable variables start with `val`; you can drop the type specification (it's inferred), and instantiating arrays is not a special case, but is just like instantiating a `List` or `Map`, etc.

```
val budgetId = budgetService.mutate(Array(budgetOperation)).getValue(0).getBudgetId()
```

The IntelliJ Scala plugin has a feature that will attempt to automatically convert Java code to Scala. While it doesn't always get it right, it may be of aid in learning how to map Java constructs into Scala.

Comment: Thank you. I had imported the wrong API. I think reading scala tutorials helped as well. 

import com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201509.cm.BudgetServiceInterface

instead of 

import com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201605.cm.BudgetServiceInterface